# Create XML files using external parameters

Tags: xml, linux

I have to create a series of XML files on Linux, but inside the XML file there is an IP address is not fixed, I have to pass this IP by parameter from exterieur.
How can I do this automatically? I know I can do this using Shell, but it's not very easy.

The XML file is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="consumer-producer-proxy"
inboundAddress="http://localhost:8090/proxy?wsdl"
outboundAddress="http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl" />   --> this should be passed from exterieur
...
```

Comment: Replace IPtoUser:192.168.0.127 with IPtoUser:{ip_to_user} and use an available language to string replace it. Python or Perl should be readily available. So a file called getXML.py should load your xml file, replace {ip_to_user} by the passed parameter i.e ip address and output the file.

Comment: Thanks, got it working